Difficulty launching a VM at startup (24.04)
I've spent the past week trying to figure out how to run a VirtualBox VM on startup with no success.
The command I'm running is VBoxManage startvm HAOS --type gui and it works perfectly when I run it from a terminal.
However, if I input the command into startup applications, I receive a pop-up error upon reboot: "The Virtualbox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly". I assume that the startup command is attempting to execute before the driver is loaded and thus failing. However, if I preface the command with sleep 10; nothing happens - i.e. no error or program startup. As with the original command, though, the delayed command works fine in a terminal.
I've tried composing and executing a script via startup applications instead /bin/bash /home/user/HAOS.sh but encounter the same problems descried above.
Am I making an obvious mistake here? How can I get my VM to load on startup? Any help much appreciated.

type gui? No GUI at startup. Possibly no GUI installed at all on a server.
Try:
VBoxManage startvm HAOS --type headless

